# How to make products/categories gridview display page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, view, grid

i want to show gridview of 9 thumbnail in set of 3 per line and same thing i want to show in products page when any one clicks on any of the one caegories and also it should be paginated. and last thing is to make single product page in which there is add to whishlist button. please tell me the solution on how to start making i am confused and not getting any idea how to make it. I have tried to make categories and tried to show it but was not able to show in grid view

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try using the Featured Grid Post plugin for WordPress?
It is very easy to config and is very customizable.

Here you are the link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-posts-grid/